# c# showdialog return whole line

Tags: c#, windows, vba

Greets.

I'm calling a Window with .ShowDialog() and returning some lines form a textbox.

The lines return back to a List<>, but each character in the textbox getting returned is getting assigned to it's own index value within the List<>.

I essentially want to add an entire line from the textbox to it's own index value in the List<>

EXAMPLE:
I enter the below in the textbox that was called from the ShowDialog();

123456
87564
125

How do I add each line from the textbox to it's own index on the list?

This is what I have now. (No code on the textbox window that I enter these values into)  (I realize I spelled it as imput...)  When I debug and review the pos List<>, each character has it's own index ID..

```
private void GetPOs()
    {
        MultiLineImput getPOList = new MultiLineImput();
        getPOList.ShowDialog();

        foreach (char po in getPOList.listOfPOs.Text)
        {
            pos.Add(po.ToString());
        }

        if (pos.Count > 0)
        {
            string a = String.Join("", pos);
            MessageBox.Show(a, "POs to Process");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!getPOList.wasCanceled.Equals(1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No values were passed", "Warning");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No worries.  I actually posted this on my phone.  Swype must have inserted it incorrectly and I clearly didn't proof read very well.

Comment: removing comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over the characters of `Text` property, so each character is converted to string and added to list separately.
I'm not sure what you mean by adding the entire "line". In your example there's only one line, so you can rewrite this loop

```
    foreach (char po in getPOList.listOfPOs.Text)
    {
        pos.Add(po.ToString());
    }
```

to simply

```
        pos.Add(getPOList.listOfPOs.Text);
```

if you meant to split this line in entries "123456", "87564", "125", you can do the following way:

```
    foreach (string po in getPOList.listOfPOs.Text.Split(' '))
    {
        pos.Add(po);
    }
```

if your textbox indeed support multiline input, you can split by `Environment.NewLine`, like this:

```
    foreach (string po in getPOList.listOfPOs.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    {
        pos.Add(po);
    }
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Bot examples were spot on. I chose this answer as it concatenates the split function with the foreach.  Thanks again.  This work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over a string, the iterator will pull one character at a time. It has no idea what a line break is.

I suggest you break the string up by line breaks, then iterate over the result, like so:

```
MultiLineInput getPOList = new MultiLineInput();
getPOList.ShowDialog();

var wholeText = getPOList.listOfPOs.Text;
var lines = wholeText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string po in getPOList.listOfPOs.Text)
{
    pos.Add(po);
}
//Etc.....
```